# What is the maximum temperature of engine bleed air for de-icing the wings?

Tags: airbus-a380, icing, boeing-747, bleed-air

What is the maximum temperature of the air bled from the engines of a Boeing 747-800 and an Airbus A380 to the wings for de-icing?  If the air is too hot, how is it cooled?

Comment: Related: [How hot would pressurized air get if the air conditioning failed?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/5031/1696)

Comment: I dont know about the maximum temp but in B777 the Wing anti ice doesnt operate with the temp below 93 degree C. The air comes from the main pneumatic duct and initially cooled through Precooler(Heat exchanger) by using fan air. The temp and pressure for the particular wing is then further controlled by its respsctive WAI(Wing anti ice ) valve.

Comment: You should narrow your question down to a specific type or design. I could give you book figures for multiple aircraft that I fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on aircraft type and manufacturer approved limitations.  Typically it’s limited by temperature or duration of use.  Compressor bleed air is tapped at around 450° F, hotter than a typical household oven.  These high temperatures can begin to significantly affect the yield strength of aluminum alloys typically used in aircraft construction, approaching the design factor said of safety and potentially resulting in a local structural compromise during high load factors, etc.