# Is the air bleeded from the engine to maintain cabin pressure for airlines heated or cooled

Tags: jet-engine, airliner, cabin-pressure, cabin-design

Is the air bleeded from the engine to maintain cabin pressure for airlines heated or cooled.  If heated, what device is used, if cooled, what device is used and in both cases how much energy does it draw for both the former and the latter

Comment: Bleed air is hot, very hot, it needs to be cooled before it can be used for pressurization.

Comment: Related: [How hot would pressurized air get if the air conditioning failed?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/5031/19)